# Как найти все файлы в строке?

Tags: php

Есть строка типа

> ......... "/data/file.js" ......... "data/sDSs.png" ...... "data/slide.css" .....

Мне нужно получить из этой строки все подстроки которые заканчивается на:

> .js | .css | .png | .jpg | .gif

И чтобы они были до первой **"**

То есть нужно получить:

/data/file.js

data/sDSs.png

data/slide.css

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: А в php есть возможность использовать регулярные выражения? (вопрос риторический)

Comment: @MBo у меня с ними сложновато....

Comment: Ну в данном случае можно и по-крестьянски - идти по строке, вcтретили кавычку - запомнили позицию. Встретили ещё раз - скопировали от запомненной позиции подстроку, проверили `strrpos` для всех расширений. Однако с регулярками это будет одной-двумя строчками

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/1m7jNJ/1

Comment: @teran, если закинуть непарную кавычку или какой-нибудь `"file.bin"`, то поломается.

Comment: @Qwertiy `file.bin` то чем поломается?

Comment: @teran, тем же, чем просто кавычка: https://regex101.com/r/1oMuMt/1.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну эт да. очевидно, что `[^"]` нужен

Answer (score 0):

Вытаскивай все совпадения по регулярке

```
"[^"]+\.(?:js|css|png|jpg|gif)"
```